# Is it possible to blend a normal map with Matcap style shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, normal-map

I was wondering if it's possible to take a tangent normal map and blend it with a matcap style normal shading similar to what's done in the sketchfab viewer?
In Cycles by the way.

This is my Matcap set up currently in blender

[image]

Sketchfab example

[image: no normal map]

[image: with normal map]